# Why is my Microsoft Windows 7 enterprise remote connection disconnecting randomly?

Tags: remote-desktop, regedit

My remote desktop connection session is being disconnected randomly/intermittently. I am using Windows 7 Enterprise and group policies are sometimes being released/pushed out to many users on our "ad" domain.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Eva G.: - This registry key controls the "Terminal Services Client" and that's used by Remote Desktop in windows. Whenever a group policy get updated or changed in any way and the admin's server pushes out that policy, this connection gets denied and forces us (the user) to re-login into whatever machine we were just connected to. Make sure this registry key is set on both the source and destination machines.[Screenshot of key in Regedit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjjzv.jpg)